# How may I install the right Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: 14.04, java

I receive following error in terminal:

```
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 1.5.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
You can also try to delete the JVM cache file
```

I'm using 14.04.

Comment: what was the command to which this error came

Comment: Just a ./ xxxxx.sh file execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the latest version of Java by opening a Terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and running

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: Unfortunately I now receive an error from my .sh installer: `testing JVM in /usr ...
Starting Installer ...
Aug 01, 2014 7:59:02 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
Information: Created user preferences directory.
ago 01, 2014 7:59:32 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
Avvertenza: Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: /etc/.java/.systemPrefs/com create failed.`

Comment: Try running the script with root privileges. Just add `sudo` in front of the `./`

Comment: It seems it cannot create the folder /etc/.java/.systemPrefs/com. In order to do that you have to run the xxxx.sh command by running as a root. That would be "sudo ./<your_file>.sh"

Comment: I guess a restart did it. I could start it up, but can't open a file with the software.